# TFS 2015 (and Octopus): Continuous integration, but wait a bit

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, octopus-deploy

When a pull request is completed, our (TFS 2015/Octopus- based) build system is set to do a build and deploy.  The problem is, we typically have a bunch of pull requests queued up, and approving each of them triggers a build and deployment, with the unnecessary packages being created/saved and resulting emails to QA that a deployment is ready. Not a critical problem perhaps, but an annoyance to be sure.

We are using vNext build definitions. I have "Batch changes" enabled, but it's not good enough (the builds take less than a minute, reviewing and approving a pull request could take 1-30 minutes).  What I would like to do is have continuous integration, but wait, say, 15 minutes after the first merge to see if any other changes are coming.

Alternatively, a scheduled build every hour, but ONLY if something has changed would suffice.
Alternatively, building every time but Octopus will only deploy after waiting a bit, that would work too.

Aside from writing my own windows service that uses the TFS REST API to trigger builds every x minutes only if something has changed, I'm not seeing a good solution.  Or I've thought about saving the build packages off somewhere and writing a service to send them to Octopus only if no new packages have arrived in x minutes.

Does anyone have something like this working?

Comment: "a scheduled build every hour, but ONLY if something has changed would suffice" - this seems to be a gap between build vNext and XAML builds.

Comment: `Rolling builds` have been updated with `Batch` option, however the `Build no more often than every X  minutes` is currently missing. [See 1st comment in the blog post from VSTFS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2016/04/01/tfs-2015-update-2-gated-checkin-for-the-new-build-system-build-vnext).

Answer (score 1):

At the places where I have implemented this, I have argued for letting the QA teams decide when (or even *if*) to deploy.  I usually implement two environments:

- DEV Integration:  Every continuous build gets deployed here.  If deployment is successful, it becomes available to the QA Team (e-mail, build quality, etc.)
- QA Environment:  Where the QA Team performs its testing.  The QA team chooses which build to deploy, and when.

You can set up permissions in Octopus Deploy to allow the QA team to "promote" a build from the DEV environment to the QA environment.  Not sure if you have the ability to set up a second environment like that, but if you can, it will give you a lot of flexibility.

Comment: I've though about doing something like this.  I wouldn't even need a separate DEV server.  I have every deployment set up to deploy to a new IIS site (named based on the release number) on the QA server.  I could give QA a script that would allow them to promote a build.  It would simply switch the site bindings from "pending-blahblah.com" to "blahblah.com"

Comment: I've also followed this approach in the past - having two environments ensures that developers can check their work after a PR, prior to QA getting their mitts on it.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep building on every checkin so that the developers have a quick feedback cycle.

To solve your problem, you could write a powershell/small app that uses the Octopus API to query what the latest release is, see if it has been deployed to QA and if not, deploy it. You can then schedule that using the windows scheduler.

Sample code using the C# Client library (not tested):

```
var project = _repository.Projects.FindByName("MyProject");
var qaEnv = _repository.Environments.FindByName("QA");
var release = _repository.Projects.GetReleases(project).Items.First();
var isDeployed = _repository.Releases.GetDeployments(release).Items.Any(i => i.EnvironmentId == qaEnv.Id); // Only returns the first 30 items, uses paging
if(!isDeployed)
    _repository.Deployments.Create(new DeploymentResource()
    {
        ProjectId = project.Id,
        ReleaseId = release.Id,
        EnvironmentId = qaEnv.Id
    })
```